# scala inheritance issue: val vs. def

Tags: scala, inheritance

Writing a simple example from Odersky's book resulted in the following problem:

```
// AbstractElement.scala
abstract class AbstractElement {
  val contents: Array[String]
  val height: Int = contents.length // line 3
}

class UnifiedElement(ch: Char, _width: Int, _height: Int) extends AbstractElement { // line 6
  val contents = Array.fill(_height)(ch.toString() * _width)
}

object AbstractElement {
  def create(ch: Char): AbstractElement = {
    new UnifiedElement(ch, 1, 1) // line 12
  }
}
```

,

```
// ElementApp.scala
import AbstractElement.create

object ElementApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val e1 = create(' ') // line 6
    println(e1.height)
  }
}
```

The compiler throws the following trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at AbstractElement.<init>(AbstractElement.scala:3)
    at UnifiedElement.<init>(AbstractElement.scala:6)
    at AbstractElement$.create(AbstractElement.scala:12)
    at ElementApp$.main(ElementApp.scala:6)
    at ElementApp.main(ElementApp.scala)
```

So the compiler thinks that contents is still null, but I defined it in UnifiedContainer!

Things get even more weird when I replace val with def and evrth works perfect!

Could you please xplain this behaviour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki/Initialization-Order) is a great article by Paul P that explains the initialization order intricacies in Scala. As a rule of thumb, you should **never** use abstract `val`s. Always use abstract `def`s and `lazy val`s.

Comment: Can you clarify 'Always use abstract `def`s and `lazy val`s? The compiler doesn't allow you to put `lazy val` in an abstract class.

Comment: Some examples I see use a `val` in the abstract class and then `lazy val` in the concrete class extending it. Is this the correct way? (I am still learning Scala so getting confused a little)

Comment: @jbx, yes. I encourage you to look at how `lazy val` is implemented, to get a deeper understanding of why this works and what benefits it provides. :)

Comment: @missingfaktor I get a 404 error with the link in your answer. I found [this blog post](http://engineering.tapad.com/blog/2012/11/here-there-be-dragons-dangers-of-initialization-order-in-scala/) useful.

Comment: @MarcoS, apparently they moved it, and I don't have the new location.

Comment: The link to the blog post is also dead :(

Comment: @DatNguyen, such is the internet of the day.

Answer (score 4):

In the definition of `AbstractElement`, you're in practice defining a constructor which initializes contents to null and computes contents.length. The constructor of `UnifiedElement` calls `AbstractElement`'s constructor and only then initializes contents.

**EDIT**: in other words, we have a new instance of a problem already existing in Java (and any OOP language): the constructor of a superclass calls a method implemented in a subclass, but the latter cannot be safely called because the subclass is not yet constructed. Abstract vals are only one of the ways to trigger it.

The simplest solution here is to just make `height` a `def`, which is better anwyay, and be aware of initialization rules linked in the other answer.

```
abstract class AbstractElement {
  val contents: Array[String]
  def height: Int = contents.length //Make this a def
}
```

The slightly more complex solution, instead, is to force `contents` to be initialized *before* height, which you can do with this syntax:

```
class UnifiedElement(ch: Char, _width: Int, _height: Int) extends {
  val contents = Array.fill(_height)(ch.toString() * _width)
} with AbstractElement {
  //...
}
```

Note that mixin composition, that is `with`, is not symmetrical - it works left-to-right. And note that `{}` at the end can be omitted, if you define no other members.

Lazy vals are also a solution, but they incur quite some run-time overhead - whenever you read the variable, the generated code will read a volatile bitmap to check that the field was already initialized.

Making `contents` a `def` here seems a bad idea, because it will be recomputed too often.

Finally, avoiding abstract vals is IMHO an extreme measure. Sometimes they are just the right thing - you should just be careful with concrete vals referring to abstract vals.

**EDIT**: It seems that instead of an abstract val, one could use an abstract definition and override it with a concrete val. That is indeed possible, but it does not help if there are concrete vals referring to the abstract definition. Consider this variant of the above code, and pay attention to how members are defined:

```
abstract class AbstractElement {
  def contents: Array[String]
  val height: Int = contents.length // line 3
}

class UnifiedElement(ch: Char, _width: Int, _height: Int) extends AbstractElement {
  val contents = Array.fill(_height)(ch.toString() * _width)
}
```

This code has the same runtime behavior as the code given by the OP, even if `AbstractElement.contents` is now a `def`: the body of the accessor reads a field which is initialized only by the subclass constructor. The only difference between an abstract value and an abstract definition seems to be that an abstract value can only be overridden by a concrete value, so it can be useful to constrain the behavior of subclasses if that is what you want.

Comment: Can you please explain how abstract `val`s are sometimes the right thing? Does it provide any advantage over "abstract `def` overridden by a concrete `val`" approach?

Comment: I thought about that, but it does not solve the problem, as I now explain.